# Android vndk in Pie

Tags: android, ipc, hal

I have added a vendor specific `hal`, I can able to build this as a separate module but during `AOSP` full build I am getting the below error. Anyone faced this issue?
Added `VNDK-core: android.hardware.uclhal@1.0.so`
 error: `VNDK` library list has been changed.
        Changing the `VNDK` library list is not allowed in API locked branches.

Comment: Hi user9486934, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you have to either disable vndk in hal's `Android.bp`, or write to `current.txt` and `28.txt` files.

##### Write to api files

You should add `VNDK-core: android.hardware.uclhal@1.0.so` to **both** `current.txt` and `28.txt` under `build/make/target/product/vndk/`

If it's not working, check that `28.txt` and `current.txt` are the same.

If it's still not working, check the generated `libs.txt` file in `out/`

```
diff $OUT/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/libs.txt build/make/target/product/vndk/28.txt

diff $OUT/obj/PACKAGING/vndk_intermediates/libs.txt build/make/target/product/vndk/current.txt
```

*(where `$OUT` is `out/target/product/PRODUCT_NAME`)*

They shouldn't be different.

If `libs.txt` is different, compare the printed to your hal's module name in `Android.bp`

```
hidl_interface {
  name: "android.hardware.uclhal@1.0"
}
```

The `hidl_interface.name` should be the same as the string you're adding to `current.txt` and `28.txt` files, but without `.so`

##### Disable it

As shrishail-satihal mentioned, you can disable it in `Android.bp`

```json
hidl_interfaces {
  // ...

  vndk : {
    enabled: false
  },
}
```

Also supported by Android 9. Check [VndkProperties](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-9.0.0_r42:build/soong/cc/vndk.go;l=25) for more details & options

Answer (score 0):

You can find a file like build/make/target/product/vndk/28.txt in your project.
Then, add a line "VNDK-core: android.hardware.uclhal@1.0.so" into the file.
After that, you may have a full build without compiling error.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a file like build/make/target/product/vndk/28.txt **and current.txt** in your project. Then, add a line "VNDK-core: android.hardware.uclhal@1.0.so" into the file **by alphabet order**. After that, you may have a full build without compiling error.

Answer (score 0):

In android R we don't have vndk folder(`build/make/target/product/vndk/`), we have gsi folder(`build/make/target/product/gsi/`) and there we can see `cureent.txt`, `28.txt`, `29.txt` etc. but adding respective .so file here doesnt worked for me. the following approach resolved my issue
disable vndk lib which is not required in `Android.bp` file for your respective hidl interface/module

```
vndk: {
    enabled: false,
},
```